# Screen flickering black when html5 video tag comes in cordova ionic app

Tags: android, cordova, android-webview, ionic4

In latest android 10+ We are facing the wired issue in Ionic application. When user try to play video screen flickering black screen. Mostly its happen in Samsung android devices. Video is not loading from internet. Its a local device video. Also, not an issue with file reading permission. As 1/10 times its work and 9 time not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Chrome 85 released today fixes this going forward. its an issue with HTML5 Video player and webview. Please update to the latest version of chrome 85 and android webview